# Set optimal size of a dialog window containing a TableWidget

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote a little dialog which only contains a TableWigdet. How can I determine the horizontal size of the table ? I want to resize the dialog window so that the table is displayed without a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to do it.  You have to sum over the widths of the table's columns and then add space for the headers.  You also have to add space for the vertical scrollbar and the widget frame.  Here is one way to do it,

```
class myTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def sizeHint(self):
        width = 0
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            width += self.columnWidth(i)

        width += self.verticalHeader().sizeHint().width()

        width += self.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()
        width += self.frameWidth()*2

        return QtCore.QSize(width,self.height())
```

Comment: A few years later, this still works. I am wondering, however, is there still no better (i.e. built-in) way of doing so (in PySide2 btw.)?

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like that (commented enough I hope):

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyTableWidget(QTableWidget):  
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent = None):
        super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(x, y, parent)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        # To force the width to use sizeHint().width()
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        # To readjust the size automatically...
        # ... when columns are added or resized
        self.horizontalHeader().geometriesChanged \
             .connect(self.updateGeometryAsync)
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized \
             .connect(self.updateGeometryAsync)        
        # ... when a row header label changes and makes the
        # width of the vertical header change too
        self.model().headerDataChanged.connect(self.updateGeometryAsync)

    def updateGeometryAsync(self):      
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.updateGeometry)

    def sizeHint(self):
        height = QTableWidget.sizeHint(self).height()

        # length() includes the width of all its sections
        width = self.horizontalHeader().length() 

        # you add the actual size of the vertical header and scrollbar
        # (not the sizeHint which would only be the preferred size)                  
        width += self.verticalHeader().width()        
        width += self.verticalScrollBar().width()       

        # and the margins which include the frameWidth and the extra 
        # margins that would be set via a stylesheet or something else
        margins = self.contentsMargins()
        width += margins.left() + margins.right()

        return QSize(width, height)
```

When a row header changes, the width of the whole vertical header changes, but not right away after the signal `headerDataChanged` is emitted.
 That's why I used a `QTimer` to call the `updateGeometry` (which must be called when  `sizeHint` changes) after `QTableWidget` has actually updated the vertical header width.

Comment: This worked fine for me, while the 'accepted' answer did not. One reason may be that I'm using a QTableView which doesn't have the columnCount method used in Mr Terry's solution. Note that with a QTableView you need to set the model early in the constructor for this solution to work because it uses the model to tell if the headers change.

Comment: Word of warning: I was using this implementation of `MyTableWidget` in a non-saved dialog (e.g. dialog was created and went out of scope in the same method), and it was giving me a `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MyTableWidget has been deleted` error. I think that the `QTimer` was trying to call `self.updateGeometry` after the widget had already been garbage collected (is that possible?). In any case, I just replaced the calls to `self.updateGeometryAsync` with calls to the stock `self.updateGeometry` and it still worked fine for me.