# How to make QDIalog auto-resize to the size of its content?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm using PyQt4.

I want to show a `QTableWidget` in a `QDialog`, and here's the code I use:

```
    w = QDialog()
    layout = QGridLayout()
    tw = QTableWidget(w)

    ... code to setup tw ...

    layout.addWidget(tw, 0, 0)
    w.setLayout(layout)
    w.exec_():
```

The resulting `QDialog` works fine except that it only shows a part of the `QTableWidget` however many columns are in the table. So I have to drag the border to resize it.

Is there a way to make the QDialog automatically resize to the right size at first ?

I tried to use `adjustSize()` and `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding))` but neither of them worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7189305/894321

Answer (score 2):

set your table like this:

```
tw.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
tw.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
tw.horizontalHeader().hide()          
tw.verticalHeader().hide()
```

resize it after you populate it:

```
tw.resizeRowsToContents()
tw.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

and then set size for dialog like this:

```
dialogWidth = tw.horizontalHeader().length() + 24
dialogHeight= tw.verticalHeader().length()   + 24
w.setFixedSize(dialogWidth, dialogHeight)
```

Dialog will automatically resize to the right size, no matter how much rows or columns you have, and what is inside of tableWidget cells

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
       w.resize(tw.width(),tw.height())
```